# Importing parent's parent ActionData in SvelteKit

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit

I have a SvelteKit project with the following structure:

```
parent/
  child/
    +page.svelte
    childsChild/
      +page.svelte
  +page.server.ts
```

In both `+page.svelte` I have `<form>`s that call the same action from `parent/+page.server.ts`, say `parent?/submitStuff`.

The problem is, when I try to import `ActionData` to display display "result".
Using

```
import type { ActionData } from './$types';
```

shows an error when I run `npm run check`.

I think the problem is that in file's current directory, `.`, there are no generated `./$types`. Is it alright if I import from `../$types` or even `../../$types`?

Thanks

Comment: I believe it should be alright. You would be telling Typescript that you want to consume  that form action instead of a potential one in the current page as per the default behaviour.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I thought. One gimmick I found is that after form submission is complete, svelte redirects me to `/parent` instead of staying at `parent/child` or `parent/child/childschild`.

Comment: Is it SvelteKit tho? If you are not enhancing your form, it is very likely that the browser itself is sending you to `/parent` and SvelteKit just moves along with it. Try using [`use:enhance`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions#progressive-enhancement-use-enhance). This will submit the form in the background (fetch-like) so you won't leave the page you are currently on. Any needed redirect can still be handled in the form action and seamlessly applied by SvelteKit once the submission completes.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, that probably would be browser behavior. I am planning to `use:enhance` as the next step in writing the app.